# Why does Core Data migration run on app launch?

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

I have successfully done Core Data lightweight model migrations before in my app, but currently I'm struggling to deal with an issue where the migration seems to run as soon as the app is updated and run, even before UIApplication's `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method is called, let alone setting up the Core Data stack. One of my goals in this migration is to fix some bug with a Transformable property, so it's vital that I load up the app's persistent store with the old model initially so I can fix some things *before* running the lightweight migration. But in my testing, it seems that the SQLite store file is changed to the new model as soon as the updated app is installed and run, which signifies that the lightweight migration has already run before the updated app is up and running.

Some details:

- my Core Data sqlite store is stored in the application container:
  `NSURL *containerURL =  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: groupIdentifier];``
- I don't use a `NSPersistentContainer` but add the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and load the `NSPersistentStore` manually, using `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error`
- I first run the app in it's existing state, and note that the SQLite store that is created is using the current Core Data model
- As soon as I run the updated app in Xcode, with the updated model schema, even if I setup a breakpoint in AppDelegate's `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, I notice that the sqlite store file has already updated to the new model, before any `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` is created or a `NSPersistentStore` is added
- For testing, I removed any app extensions (like widgets and App Shortcuts), so they don't cause any confusion. Same issue occurs.
- I created a new Core Data template project (which uses `NSPersistentContainer`) and ran a similar test there (running the app with original model, then updating the model and running it again), and in this case, it works as expected ... the Sqlite store file still shows the old model until the `NSPersistentContainer` is loaded

What's the best explanation for this issue, and/or the best way to debug something like this? I'm a bit stumped, and don't know where to look.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the code where you load the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`? You mention `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, but loading the coordinator is where the migration would occur.

Comment: The breakpoint is at the beginning of `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ... well before the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` is created. I even set the breakpoint in main.m and same issue.

Comment: I see. It wasn't clear that you load the persistent store coordinator in that function. I don't know what's causing this, but migration doesn't happen until something in your code triggers it-- so if it were me, I'd probably try adding more breakpoints on almost anything that might touch Core Data. I would also try creating a symbolic (not a line of code, but that function) breakpoint on the `addPersistentStore...` methods of `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, to be sure to catch them if they're triggered unexpectedly somehow.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to figure something out ... I have a few extensions in my app (watch, share extension, Siri, widgets etc), and though I thought I had tested by removing them all, I must've missed something. All the extensions share a common method to load the PSC as well, and when I set the `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` to NO in that method, it avoids the problem. Not sure which of the extensions is loaded before the main app runs, and whether there's any way to control the order, but at least I've found the root issue here